# How to define type of an object to accept only keys from enum?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

Then I have a method of React Component which should return an object, whose keys can only be string keys of MyEnum (meaning, so far: One, Two, Three):

```
myFunction = (someValue: {}[]): {} => {
    return someValue.reduce((res, v, i) => {
         res[v.name].push(v)
         return res
    }, {})
}
```

**Question:** How can I dynamically define the type of the return value of this function to be an object, whose keys can only be string keys of MyEnum?

Right now there are only 3 of them, but if I add another one to the enum, the type of the return value of myFunction should also be updated.

**Update 1:**

Tried assigning `Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, any>` as a return value:

```
myMethod = (someValue: {}[]): Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, any> => {
    return someValue.reduce((res: any, v: SomeInterface) => {
         res[v.name].push(v)
         return res
    }, {})
}
```

This does not throw any errors, but if I assign the return value of reduce to a variable and then add another property on it (whose key is not MyEnum key), there would be no error, which is not what I seek:

```
myMethod = (someValue: {}[]): Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, any> => {
    let someVar = someValue.reduce((res: any, v: SomeInterface) => {
         res[v.name].push(v)
         return res
    }, {})
    someVar.keyName = 'value'
    return someVar
}
```

Comment: `Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, any>`?

Comment: @jcalz What is "Record"?

Comment: A type in the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1379-L1384) where `Record<K,V>` means "an object with keys `K` and values `V`".

Comment: @jcalz I have a .reduce method, which yields the return value. And the whole construct is being underlined with an error that one of the string values of MyEnum is missing in the return value of the function.

Comment: Can you edit the relevant code and errors into your question along with the compiler error so someone can help you debug?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! Done.

Comment: Thanks... you might want to add enough info to be a [mcve]. For example, `someValue` can't be `{}` because there's no `reduce` method on that.  Can you specify the typing for `reduce`?

Comment: @jcalz Corrected. How can typing for reduce be specified? Reduce returns {}[].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it looks like there's a lot of stuff going on here. My observations and guesses:

- Since `v` is `SomeInterface`, it seems that `someValue` must be an array of `SomeInterface`.
- I am guessing that `res` in the body of `reduce`'s callback function is the desired return value of `myMethod`, since you're setting values on it in the callback function.  If we call the type of return value of `myMethod` by the name `RetType`, that means the keys of `RetType` must be `keyof typeof MyEnum`.
- You are using `v.name` as those keys, and since `v` is `SomeInterface`, then I guess that `SomeInterface`'s `name` property should also be `keyof typeof MyEnum`.
- You are `push`ing `v` onto the values of `res`, so you expect the properties of `res` to be arrays of `SomeInterface`.  Hence, `RetType` is something like `Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, SomeInterface[]>`, where [`Record<K,V>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1379-L1384) is a type from the standard library representing an object with keys in `K` and values in `V`.
- But of course, since `someValue` might be an empty array, or otherwise not have as many elements as the keys of `MyEnum`, then `RetType` might be missing some properties.  So it is more like `Partial<Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, SomeInterface[]>>`, where [`Partial<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1351-L1356) is a type from standard library which makes the properties in `T` optional.
- Now, I'm not sure if you fully understand the way [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works, but the callback needs to return something of the same type as the intended return value.  And the second argument is "initial value" which must also be the same type as the intended return value.  Thus I have to change your callback so that it returns `res`, and the initial value so that it is too of `RetType`.
- I also note that since the initial value is an empty object, the first time you try to `push` something onto one of its array properties, you will find that it is `undefined`.  So you need to check for that and set it to an empty array before you try to `push` onto it.

That leads me to something like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}

interface SomeInterface {
  name: keyof typeof MyEnum
};

type RetType = Partial<Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, SomeInterface[]>>

const myMethod = (someValue: SomeInterface[]): RetType => {
  let someVar = someValue.reduce((res: RetType, v: SomeInterface) => {
    const resVName = res[v.name] || []; // make sure it's set
    resVName.push(v);
    res[v.name]=resVName; // copy back in case it's a new array
    return res;
  }, {} as RetType)
  //someVar.keyName = 'value' // errors now
  return someVar
}
```

Note that I copy to and from a new value called `resVName`.  This allows the compiler's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to work and be sure that `resVName` is actually a `SomeInterface[]` and not a `SomeInterface[] | undefined`.  It doesn't work on `res[v.name]` because of a [bug/limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) in TypeScript whereby control flow analysis doesn't work with bracket property access notation.  It's a bit annoying but ensuring type safety is probably worth it.

That code is all well typed and may possibly work at runtime (you'd need to check).  But `reduce` doesn't seem like what you're trying to do.  Instead, I'd say you're looking for the simpler [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, like this:

```
const myMethod = (someValue: SomeInterface[]): RetType => {
  let someVar: RetType = {};
  someValue.forEach((v: SomeInterface) => {
    const someVarVName = someVar[v.name] || []; // make sure it's set
    someVarVName.push(v);
    someVar[v.name] = someVarVName; // copy back in case it's a new array
  });
  //someVar.keyName = 'value'
  return someVar
}
```

That also works and doesn't mess around with passing around the accumulator.  Either way is fine, probably.

---

Okay hope that makes some sense and gives you ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: Amazing answer! Was absolutely worth it to elaborate on the initial question by your request. Thank you very much!
I missed your points 2 and 4 and partially point 5: the rest of the point 5, plus the entire point 6 was inadvertently omitted in the question.

Comment: but what is the problem with `reduce`?

Comment: Well, `reduce` is a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) operation which builds up a final return value from intermediate return values.  But in your case the return value is always the same, and you're just mutating the data in it.  So `reduce` is unnecessary, and you might as well use `forEach`, which doesn't care about the return value.